# PL/pgSQL: merge results from iterative function call in another function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function `func1(ID int)` that returns rows for a given ID.

I have another function `func2(IDs int[])` that gets an array of IDs and uses a loop to call `func1` for each ID, finally it should combine all results and return it.

Both functions return `SETOF y` so they are compatible in their schema of columns.

What I want to do is inside the loop of `func2()` to merge the results. If it was in the same SQL query I would simply use `UNION` but the results are from a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(IDs integer[]) RETURNS SETOF y AS
$BODY$
declare 
    a_id int;
    r y;
begin
  FOREACH a_id IN ARRAY $1
  LOOP
    SELECT * into r FROM  func1(a_id) ; 
    //CODE TO ENTER FOR UNION EACH ITERATION WITH THE LAST ONE
  END LOOP;
return;
end;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

`r` should contain the result of a single call to `func1()`. How do I combine all `r` and return them?

In simple words it should do: `func1(1st ID) UNION func1(2nd ID) UNION ... UNION func1(nth ID)` and return it to whom ever called `func2(IDs int[])`.

Comment: `r := r UNION ALL SELECT * FROM  func1(a_id)`  should work

Comment: can you explain it ? I don't understand what you wrote. `y` is a type not a variable...  why do u use `:=`  if you also use `into r`?

Comment: my bad.. yes `r`.. and edited.

Comment: it doesn't work : `ERROR: INTO is only allowed on first SELECT of UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `func1()` returns a set, you can use it as a table source in a simple query. In `func2()`, which returns a set of the same row type, you can iterate over the array values and call `func1()` and add the returned set to the result set of the current function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(IDs integer[]) RETURNS SETOF y AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  a_id int;
BEGIN
  FOREACH a_id IN ARRAY $1
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM func1(a_id); 
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE STRICT;
```

In a `RETURNS SETOF` function [`RETURN QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) will add results to the result set on successive calls. Only an unadorned `RETURN` statement will return the data to the caller. In effect, all returned `y`'s from all calls are returned from `func2()`.

Note also that your function is not `VOLATILE` but `STABLE`. The latter mode is used for functions that give the same result for multiple table scans if the table does not change. It performs better than `VOLATILE` functions.

I have also made the function `STRICT`: no point in trying to find rows if no IDs are supplied.

Comment: Thank you...  `RETURN QUERY` perform an actual call to `func1` on the specific iteration or it builds the SQL statment and runs it at the end of `func2`?

Comment: See the documentation (link added in answer). The query with the call to `func1()` is executed and the results appended to an internal buffer on every iteration. It does not build a single SQL statement and that would also be very complicated in certain cases.

Comment: Thank you. I have a follow up little question. What if I want to do some manipulations over the data before sending it back? meaning between the `END LOOP;`  and the  `RETURN;` how do I access the data that the loop created? suppos i want something simple like `SELECT * FROM ?? ORDER BY something`

Comment: No, there is no way to get at the data inside the function. But you could do so on the outside: `SELECT * FROM func2(ARRAY[3, 4, 5]) ORDER BY 1`. And you could of course do that in a `func3()` if you so desire...

Comment: Thx just wanted to be sure before I write another function to wrap this one.